# Remove character and following characters in specific element

Tags: html, jquery

Attempting to remove the `-` in each `td` and the characters the come **after** it.

For example `<td>36 - 71</td>` becomes `<td>36</td>`

Current HTML

```
<tbody>
<tr><td>36 - 71</td></tr>
<tr><td>72 - 143</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

JQuery test

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
var div = $('tbody');
div.html(div.html().replace(/\-/g, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to loop over each `td` individually. You can pass a function to `text()` to implicitly loop over the `td` cells and perform the action on each of them in turn.

Also note that your current code only removes the `-` character. If you want to remove all text after the hyphen, then you can use `split()` and get the first value from the resulting array.

Try this:

```js
$('table tr td:first-child').text((i, t) => t.split('-')[0].trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>36 - 71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>72 - 143</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Rory, thank you! That was fast and accomplished what I was attempting.

Comment: No problem, glad to help